# Why is my backbone collection `undefined` for one module but not another?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, js-amd

I have the following two routes.  This one works as expected:

```javascript
panel:function(){
  app.layout.setView("div#content", new Answer.Views.Panel({
    collection:this.answers,
    useTemplate:"panels/"+path
  }));
  app.layout.render();
},
```

This one does not:

```javascript
parkingNonDowntown:function() {
  var panel = new(Answer.Views.Panel.extend(ParkingNonDowntown.Views.Calculator.prototype))({
    collection: this.answers,
    useTemplate: "panels/requirements/city/parking_non_downtown"
  });
  app.layout.setView("div#content", panel);
  app.layout.render();
},
```

I am able to access the collection from the template in the former like:

`<% answers.field_name %>`

But the same code gives `undefined` in a template that uses the second route.

I don't think the collection is being overridden in ParkingNonDowntown.Views.Calculator - the ParkingNonDowntown module only extends Backbone.View.

`this.answers` is set to be `new Answer.collection()`, which looks like this:

```javascript
// Default collection.
Answer.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Answer.Model,
  url: '/answers',      
});
```

I realise this probably isn't enough information but does anyone have any pointers? (The code is [open source](https://github.com/codeforamerica/opencounter/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/app) if that helps.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `new (Answer.Views.Panel.extend(ParkingNonDowntown.Views.Calculator.prototype))`?

Comment: The Answer model has a collection in it which I want shared across other modules.  I want it to be an `Answer.Views.Panel` but I have specific functionality in `ParkingNonDowntown.Views.Calculator` which are required for this particular page.  I think...is this a weird thing to do?  I'm new to backbone and this isn't actually my code.

Comment: Yeah, that's a little strange. Embedding your calculator inside the panel would be a lot less strange.